# C#: How to use arrays, chars and strings? Clear up needed

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and I have a project in my Algorithm class. What we have to do is decide on a problem and solve it. We haven't learnt much more than string, char and WriteLine. We did add a couple of things as you will see soon!

I decided that what I want to solve this: The user inserts a word, no matter how long and the program will automatically make the first letter a capital letter. So far this is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    start:
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word below:");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        char char1;
        if (str[0] >= 97)
        {
            char1 = (char)(str[0] - 32);
        }
        else
        {
            char1 = (char)(str[0] + 32);
        }

        char char2 = (char)(str[1]);
        char char3 = (char)(str[2]);
        char char4 = (char)(str[3]);
        char char5 = (char)(str[4]);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write(char1);
        Console.Write(char2);
        Console.Write(char3);
        Console.Write(char4);
        Console.WriteLine(char5);
        goto start;
}
}
}
```

The problem with that code is that any word with less than 5 letters will make the program crash. Anything with more than 5 letters will just be cut at the fifth letter... I was told that using arrays should solve this problem. Seeing as I am a total newbie at this, I would need this to be broken down and be as simply told as possible!

Any help getting this to work would be very appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: My heart skipped a beat at the "goto"...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx - the first link in google for "c# array". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx - the second. Please don't hesitate to read it

Comment: And if the program crashes.. try debugging and reporting back on what the error is..

Comment: All the problems aside, I appreciate someone prefacing it that it is homework and that you took a stab at the answer before just throwing it up on SO

Comment: Edited it with the full code. What is the problem with goto?

Comment: C# contains several features such as do- and while-loops which, if nothing else, increase code readability.  [But what is the worst that could happen? ... :)](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a word:");
string str = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(str[0].ToString().ToUpper() + str.Substring(1));
```

This will work.

Or... if you need to go through the entire string and find the first actual alphabetical character, you can do the following:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word:");
string s = Console.ReadLine();
bool found = false;
char[] chars = new char[s.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(s[i]) && !found)
    {
         chars[i] = s[i].ToString().ToUpper()[0];
         found = true;
    }
    else
    {
        chars[i] = s[i];
    }
}
s = new String(chars);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: What if `str` is just 1 character long?

Comment: I am getting this error: Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'SubString' and no extension method 'SubString' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Gil\Desktop\Shahar\בית ספר\מדעית הנדסית\אלגוריטמיקה\עבודה מס' 1\5 אותיות\5 אותיות\Program.cs 14 65 5 אותיות

Comment: Where exactly do I need to put it?

Comment: @user1775610 Put str.Substring(1) instead of str.SubString(1)

Comment: @Nick: Yep, "Empty if startIndex is equal to the length of this instance." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx

Comment: @Nick that doesn't make sense, why put str.Substring(1) instead of str.SubString(1)? What did you actually mean?

Comment: @zerkms Just checked also. When I saw "throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException" I thought "No way, a bug" but then I saw the MSDN

Comment: @user1775610 I mean that the method name is Substing() not SubString(), it won't compile because of that

Comment: Ok, I fixed my answer to fix the casing on Substring(). I also included a new solution if OP actually wanted the first alphabetical character of the string capitalized, which is what I suspect may be the case.

Comment: This is working. I will save this as well as mine and show it to my teacher! Would there be a way of just changing or adding a couple of things in the code I posted to do it? So that I would understand it?

Comment: The main difference in our code is simply the use of a loop. With the max iterations being set as the length of the provided string, you can ensure that there is no IndexOutOfBounds exception being thrown nor will you stop prematurely before the whole string is processed.  You should take a look a for loops specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop like this after writing char1 to the Console:

```
if (str.Length > 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)// Start at 1 to skip char1
    {
        Console.Write(str[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks good but maybe add some more notes on why to use this to new user

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods you can call on [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) that will be helpful:

- `Substring`
- `ToUpper`

In fact, you don't need to worry about characters; this problem can be solved using only strings.

Also take care to check that your code handles the case where the string is empty (using an `if` statement), which will happen if the user just presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without typing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking an algorithms class and they make you choose a problem to solve? Sounds dangerous for someone learning.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word below:");
Console.WriteLine("");
string inputString = Console.ReadLine();    // try to use meaningful variable names

// shorthand for the if ... else block:
// type variableName = (true/false condition) ? "is true" : "is false";
char firstChar = inputString[0] >= 97 ? (char)(inputString[0] - 32) : (char)(inputString[0] + 32);

Console.WriteLine("");
Console.Write(firstChar);

for (int i = 1; i < inputString.Length; i++)    // skip firstChar
{
    Console.Write(inputString[i]);
}
```

As others have mentioned, you need to use a loop for this if you want anything resembling a general solution.

Also, you'll want to avoid using goto statements. There are many reasons, one being that they (in my opinion) make code difficult to read and maintain.

Additionally, if your code had worked as written, it would never end. Your program, as written would execute, then begin again, never stopping.  If you want this sort of behavior, then you should wrap your code in an infinite loop which exits upon some condition. This might look something like:

```
bool keepRunning = true;
while(keepRunning){
    //code here
    Console.Write("go again? (y/n) ");
    keepRunning = (string)(Console.ReadLine()).equals("y") ? false : true;  
}
```

On that last statement, I forget if you need to cast the output of ReadLine to a string before calling the [.equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx.aspx) method... I don't have my IDE up. i think you get the idea.

edit: I saw another response that was just posed about using the `.ToUpper` method. I thought of this but assumed maybe you needed to use the `char` type.

Comment: I will try this! Explained very well :) Thanks!